# Lazy Singleton persisting across users

Tags: c#, session, design-patterns, singleton, dispose

I have a Lazy Singleton that is used as a reference object for a web application.

It stores basic properties that are refrenenced throughout the application:

```
public class Context
{
    public string UserName;
    public Guid TenantId;

    public static Context Current { get { return lazy.Value; } }
    private static readonly Lazy<Context> lazy = 
                              new Lazy<Context>(() => new Context());
}
//In Action
public static Something GetSomethingForUser()
{
    return DataAccess.GetSomethingForCurrentUser(Context.Current.UserName);
}
```

The problem is, if a user logs in and out my `Context` is persisting across sessions.

This isn't unexpected, I'm not disposing it.

Where should I do that? What's the best method?

Should I do it on sign out?

```
    public void SignOut()
    {
        Context.Dispose();
        HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(
            OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
              CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    }
```

Comment: If your data is dependent on the users session *store it in the users's session data* rather than in some form of data storage that is entirely independent of the user's session (or for that matter, even a particular user).  Well, that is, unless your entire system will never have more than one user.

Comment: What about disposing of PARTS of the singleton? Like just username and tenantid, etc..., but leaving the other reference objects intact?

Comment: The object that you're trying to represent is simply not inherently something that should only exist once in the entirety of your application.  Making it a singleton is inherently wrong (again, unless your entire application never has more than one user).  Your whole line of questioning is inherently flawed.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, signout should be an event other classes can register to and act properly in response to it.

The way you are using the singleton seems okay to me if you only have 1 active user at a time.

Another solution which would removed the signout problem, such has the data inside the singleton should be put inside the session itself.